# Check if values of 1 column in 1 dataframe is between values of 2 columns of another non-identical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df1 (usually containing 100k rows or more) with values - 
[Dataframe with values to be checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdiMP.png)

I have a second dataframe, df2 which is used for checking and it has the following shape - 
[Dataframe for checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQaj.png)

I need to do the following -

Check if every value of df1['A'] is between df2['Min'] and df2['Max']. If the answer is True, then provide the corresponding value from  df2['CalOffset'] into a separate column in df1['Cal_Factor']. If the test is False, return None.

Desired output - 
[Dataframe after checking values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLBPD.png)

Please let me know if this is unclear.
I have tried using np.where however as the dataframes are not identical in shape, I get an error message - "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Comment: Please post your dataframes as text instead of links to images outside. It helps people replicate your problem more easily without having to leave SO

Comment: I am not allowed yet to post my dataframes. When i copy the tables from excel, SO asks me to embed the image instead of copying the text. If you know of a better approach, please advice.